# How to know if the incoming data is equal to the last row, first column of a CSV file

Tags: python, csv, raspberry-pi

I'm reading some QR codes on Raspberry Pi, and I'm writing that data on a CSV file, but the problem is, when the data is received, it gets spammed in the CSV file, by that I mean that as soon as the QR code gets detected, it will keep writing the data on the CSV as long as the QR is being shown to the Cam, and I want that data to be written only once.

The CSV file contains only a header that says `"Orders:"`.
I'm writing inside that CSV, the data, date, and time, each in a column
What I thought of, and tried to do but didn't work, is to check whether the data is equal to the first column of the last row of the CSV file, if so then `pass`, else write the data, as follows:

```
import csv
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
detector = cv2.QRCodeDetector()

from datetime import date, datetime

today = date.today()
date = today.strftime("%d-%b-%Y")

now = datetime.now()
timeRN = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")

while True:

  _, img = cap.read()  
    data, bbox, _ = detector.detectAndDecode(img)
    
    if(bbox is not None):
        for i in range(len(bbox)):
            cv2.line(img, tuple(bbox[i][0]), tuple(bbox[(i+1) % len(bbox)][0]), color=(255,
                     0, 0), thickness=2)
        cv2.putText(img, data, (int(bbox[0][0][0]), int(bbox[0][0][1]) - 10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
                    1, (255, 250, 120), 2)
    
    if 'OrderNr' in data:
        with open('Orders.csv', mode='a+') as csvfile:
            
            csvfileWriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
            reader = readline()[-1]       
            lastRow = reader[-1]
            firstColumn = reader[1]
            if data in firstColumn:
                pass
            else:
                csvfileWriter.writerow([data, date, timeRN]) 
        a, b, c, d = data.split(',')
        print("data: ", a)
        print(b)
        print(c)
        print(d)
        lcd_print(a, b, c, d)   #just a method to print on LCD
        pass
```

When I try this, what i get is

```
lastRow = reader[-1]
IndexError: string index out of range
```

What am I doing wrong here? and is the way I'm doing it wrong? If yes, then is there any other way or simpler way to do what I'm trying to do?

**EDIT:** Code Edited

Comment: What is `reader.empty`? Isn't `reader` a list of lines in your code? AFAIK, lists don't have an `empty` attribute or property.

Comment: No, I put it only to check whether the csv is empty or not, but it can be removed, It won't matter. I only need to check whether `data` matches the first column of last row inside the csv file.

Comment: You open the file for appending, so the file pointer starts at the end of the file.  As a result, `csvfile.readlines()` reads nothing. Where is `data` coming from? Your code doesn't define or import it. Please provide a few example lines of the .csv (like the first few and the last few)

Comment: In other words, please provide a [mre].

Comment: I will edit my question to show how i get it, but the data is generated from the QR code

Comment: I saw that the mode `a+` is for reading and writing, i will try to check if there is another mode for read and write. or maybe can i read the file once, and after reading, open it for writing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep a variable that always holds the latest data. If the newly read data is equal to that, you ignore it and write to the file otherwise.

The relevant code changes are below.

```
....

latest = None

while True:

  _, img = cap.read()  
    data, bbox, _ = detector.detectAndDecode(img)

    ....
    
    if 'OrderNr' in data:
        with open('Orders.csv', mode='a+') as csvfile:
            
            csvfileWriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

            if data != latest:
                csvfileWriter.writerow([data, date, timeRN])
                latest = data
```